# Move data from Excel to Word and reformat it

Tags: excel, formatting, ms-word, migration

is there a way to move the data from an excel sheet to a word document and reformat it. I'd like the data in the first column to be formatted as 'Heading1' and the data in the second column to be formatted as 'Normal'.

So that every row results in a header and a content, but without a table itself.

Comment: Do you have any language requirements?  This is probably doable w/ VBA using the Office COM objects but it might be easier with some of the .NET Office libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the Office file formats, you may be able to do an XML XSLT transform.

Comment: I know, but I was looking for someting out of the box. thx anyway

Comment: Could you give an example, or cite some manual pages or a guide?